# Flashing Custom Recovery (TWRP): Are there risks involved beside the usual?

Tags: rooting, rom-flashing, twrp, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1

I am looking to flash twrp on my device. Are there any risks involved in it, beside the bricking,etc.

I understand that the bootloader will be unlocked, but is this any risk of something such as a privacy issue?

Twrp is supported on my device which is a Samsung Galaxy note 10.1 2014 edition smp605.

Answer (score 1):

The risks that are commonly mentioned, as RMarkwald said, are **bricking your device** and **not being able to receive OTA updates**. In my opinion, though, if you install a custom recovery such as TWRP, is because you want more control and flexibility than those provided by a stock device.

Regarding privacy... it must be said that, very often, a mere combination of keys and physical access to your device are required to start the recovery, thus enabling a potentially ill-willed user to perform malicious operations.

Now, on a stock (**3e**) recovery, the possible operations are very few, the worst being a factory reset. From a custom recovery such as TWRP, though, one could:

- **sideload and install unsigned ZIP packages**;
- **format only selected partitions**;
- **push and pull files arbitrarily**;
- **change file permissions and ownerships**;
- **convert user apps to system apps**;
- **features both a terminal and a file manager**.

---

May this serve as a general overview. Thanks to @DanB for the reminder.

Comment: Probably worth pointing out that twrp allows the wiping of /system, and of a few other partitions, AND has a Terminal, so smart kids could wipe out the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the bootloader will be unlocked, that'll remain locked.

Risks?  Bricking the device, not being able to take an OTA update are the big ones.  If you flash something not meant for your device, you could brick/cause issues requiring you to get back to stock.

I'd recommend making sure you know how to flash and get back to 100% stock before flashing a recovery/rooting the phone.

Comment: Thank you for that insight, I will surely look into getting 100% back to stock before I root my device. I really only intended on flashing CyanogenMod, a version supported, so not too worried about that.